# executing the same code line

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I have different types of Level Units that currently spawn at random using this code:

```
 let diceRoll = arc4random_uniform(2)

    if (diceRoll == 0) {

            imageName = "Road"
            theType = LevelType.road

    } else if (diceRoll == 1) {

            imageName = "Water"
            theType = LevelType.water
    }
```

But I am currently trying to get a level unit to spawn a certain number of times before allowing other level units to spawn (eg. I would like the road level type to spawn 20 times before allowing the randomiser to change level types I am currently using this code to spawn the level units:

```
    var levelBoolean:Bool = false
    let diceRoll = arc4random_uniform(1)
    let LevelBlock: [Int] = [0, 1] // 1 , 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    let numberOfLevelUnitsSpawned = 20

    if(levelBoolean == false)  {

        levelBlockRandomiser = LevelBlock[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(LevelBlock.count)))]

            levelBoolean = true   
    }

    if (levelBoolean == true) {

        if (levelBlockRandomiser == 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfLevelUnitsSpawned); i++) {

                imageName = "Road"
                theType = LevelType.road
                i++
            }
          }
        }

    if (levelBlockRandomiser == 1) {

        for (var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfLevelUnitsSpawned); i++) {

                imageName = "Water"
                theType = LevelType.water
                i++

            }
          }
```

all i'm trying to do is get a level type to spawn a certain number of times and then get another level type to spawn after that one has been completed.

What am I doing Wrong?

**EDIT:**

Not sure if I explained this well enough but when a level unit is generated in game it first must determine which level type it will be for that one level unit. the code to spawn the level unit is in another class.

So it is constantly asking what level type the one after it will be so it goes back to the start and goes through it again to determine what the next level type will be for the next level unit and so on and so forth.

What I am trying to achieve with the for loops and the boolean variable that I have, is to get it to pick a certain level type over again until is reaches 20 of the same level type and then randomises through the level types again and picks again. but it doesn't seem to want to do that because It keeps spawning different level types randomly.

**EDIT 2:**

Ok so the level generation code is:

```
var initialUnits:Int = 10 

func addLevelUnits() {

    for (var i = 0; i < initialUnits; i++ ) {

        createLevelUnit()   
    }
}

func createLevelUnit() {

    let levelUnit:LevelUnit = LevelUnit()
    worldNode.addChild(levelUnit)
    levelUnit.zPosition = -1
    levelUnit.levelUnitWidth = screenWidth
    levelUnit.levelUnitHeight = levelUnitHeight
    levelUnit.direction = direction
    levelUnit.setUpLevel()

    levelUnit.position = CGPointMake( 0 ,  levelUnitCounter * levelUnitHeight)

    levelUnitCounter++

}
```

The setUpLevel function that the code is referencing is what picks the level type which is contained within the level class which is what i'm trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loops are a bit broken at the moment - you are incrementing `i` at the `for` and also within each loop. Therefore you will get i = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, etc. You're also setting the same imageName and theType variables over and over. This code should look more like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfLevelUnitsSpawned); i++) {
     imageName = "Water" // These 2 lines are still wrong though
     theType = LevelType.water
}
```

Comment: You're right. I will take that part out of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops don't do anything, they are just repeatedly set the value of a variable but they are not really spawning new sprites

The loop needs to have the spawning code inside of it, e.g. :

```
for (var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfLevelUnitsSpawned); i++) {
   imageName = "Road"
   theType = LevelType.road

   spawnNewObject(imageName, theType)
}
```

Comment: so I explained my situation more in the edit section of my original post. The problem I have is that the code to generate the level unit is in another class.  @Michael

Comment: @Astrum Code being in another class is not a problem. Please, add the generation so that we can help you.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at it? @Sulthan